# How can I left join with a nested query in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I have this query in sequelize which is returning data but the join skews my sum aggregate.  Here is the code...

```
key: "listGoogleTextAds",
    prototype:
      "(customer_id: Int, start_date: String, end_date: String): [GoogleTextAds]",
    run: async args => {
      const allIds = await google_text_ads
        .findAll({
          attributes: [
            "ad_id",
            [sequelize.fn("max", sequelize.col("google_text_ads.date")), "date"],
            [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("google_text_ads.impressions")), "impressions"],
            [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("google_text_ads.clicks")), "clicks"],
            [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("google_text_ads.cost")), "cost"]
          ],
          where: {
            customer_id: args.customer_id,
            date: {
              [Op.gte]: args.start_date,
              [Op.lte]: args.end_date
            },
            status: {
              [Op.in]: ["ENABLED"]
            },
            type: {
              [Op.in]: ["EXPANDED_TEXT_AD"]
            }
          },
          group: ["ad_id"],
          include: [
            {
              model: google_ads_group_name,
              as: 'google_ads_group_name',
              required: true,
              attributes: [
                "ad_group_name",
                "ad_group_id"
              ],
              where: {
                customer_id: args.customer_id,
                date: {
                  [Op.gte]: args.start_date,
                  [Op.lte]: args.end_date
                },
                status: {
                  [Op.in]: ["ENABLED"]
                }
              },
              required: false
            },
          ]
        })
        .map(item => item.toJSON());
      const textAds = uniqBy(
        await google_text_ads.findAll({
          where: sequelize.where(
            sequelize.fn(
              "concat",
              sequelize.col("ad_id"),
              "-",
              sequelize.col("date")
            ),
            {
              [Op.in]: allIds.map(({ ad_id, date }) => `${ad_id}-${date}`)
            }
          )
        }),
        ({ ad_id, date }) => `${ad_id}-${date}`
      );
      return textAds.map(ad => {
        const idMap = allIds.find(({ ad_id }) => ad_id === ad.ad_id);
        return {
          ...ad.toJSON(),
          clicks: idMap.clicks,
          impressions: idMap.impressions,
          cost: idMap.cost,
          google_ads_group_name: idMap.google_ads_group_name
        };
      });
    }
  }
```

I was able to write the correct query which returns everything correctly.  I'm just confused as to how to achieve a nested left join in sequelize.  Appreciate any advice.  Here's the working query...

```
SELECT 
  `google_text_ads`.`ad_id`,
  MAX(`google_text_ads`.`date`) AS `date`,
  SUM(`google_text_ads`.`impressions`) AS `impressions`,
  SUM(`google_text_ads`.`clicks`) AS `clicks`,
  SUM(`google_text_ads`.`cost`) AS `cost`,
  ra.ad_group_name
FROM
  `google_text_ads` AS `google_text_ads`
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT
      ad_group_name,
      ad_group_id
    FROM 
      google_ads_groups 
    GROUP BY
      ad_group_id
  ) ra 
ON google_text_ads.ad_group_id = ra.ad_group_id     
WHERE
  `google_text_ads`.`customer_id` = 139
  AND (`google_text_ads`.`date` >= '2022-09-07'
  AND `google_text_ads`.`date` <= '2022-10-06')
  AND `google_text_ads`.`status` IN ('ENABLED')
  AND `google_text_ads`.`type` IN ('EXPANDED_TEXT_AD')
GROUP BY `ad_id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

So the trick is to let you sum aggregate colums query to run by itself.  Then run a second query where you map to the id's you've already found.  This keeps your aggregates pure and can still do an additional join!

```
{
  key: "listGoogleSiteLinks",
  prototype:
    "(customer_id: Int, start_date: String, end_date: String): [GoogleAdExtensions]",
  run: async args => {
    const allIds = await google_ad_extensions
      .findAll({
        attributes: [
          "extension_feed_item_id",
          [sequelize.fn("max", sequelize.col("google_ad_extensions.date")), "date"],
          [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("google_ad_extensions.impressions")), "impressions"],
          [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("google_ad_extensions.clicks")), "clicks"],
          [sequelize.fn("sum", sequelize.col("google_ad_extensions.cost_micros")), "cost"]
        ],
        where: {
          customer_id: args.customer_id,
          date: {
            [Op.gte]: args.start_date,
            [Op.lte]: args.end_date
          }
        },
        group: ["extension_feed_item_id"]
      })
      .map(item => item.toJSON());
    const adExtensions = uniqBy(
      await google_ad_extensions.findAll({
        where: sequelize.where(
          sequelize.fn(
            "concat",
            sequelize.col("extension_feed_item_id"),
            "-",
            sequelize.col("google_ad_extensions.date")
          ),
          {
            [Op.in]: allIds.map(
              ({ extension_feed_item_id, date }) =>
                `${extension_feed_item_id}-${date}`
            )
          }
        ),
        include: [
          {
            model: google_ads_group_name,
            as: 'google_ads_group_name',
            required: true,
            attributes: [
              "ad_group_name",
              "ad_group_id"
            ],
            where: {
              customer_id: args.customer_id,
              date: {
                [Op.gte]: args.start_date,
                [Op.lte]: args.end_date
              }
            }
          },
        ]
      }),
      ({ extension_feed_item_id, date }) =>
        `${extension_feed_item_id}-${date}`
    );

    return adExtensions.map(ad => {
      const idMap = allIds.find(
        ({ extension_feed_item_id }) =>
          extension_feed_item_id === ad.extension_feed_item_id
      );
      return {
        ...ad.toJSON(),
        clicks: idMap.clicks,
        impressions: idMap.impressions,
        cost: idMap.cost,
        google_ads_group_name: ad.google_ads_group_name
      };
    });
  }
},
```